# How do i allow one person to use a command with powers?

Tags: javascript, discord

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

      if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return;
      const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
      message.delete().catch();
      message.channel.send(sayMessage);

}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "say"
}
```

thats my code but im trying to have the power to ADMIN and myself.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can get the message senders user id from `message` and then compare that with the user id of the person you want to give rights to use the command

Comment: I am a little bit confused here. Are you trying to make the bot only available to be used by one person? Or are you trying to make the bot give administrator power in a server?

Comment: im trying to make it only allowed for admins and a person who isnt admin

Answer (score 0):

You need to [fetch the user's ID](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-) whom you want to allow the command to be used that is not an admin.
Afterwards, all you have to do is to check if the sender's ID matches the desired user's id.

In your `if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return;`
Add a condition of `message.user.id != "That Person's ID here"`

Resulting into:

```
if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR") || message.user.id != "That Person's ID here") {
     return;
}
```

making the command only allowed for admins and a person who isn't admin.
(Also, compare the IDs as string since they are relatively large numbers, would get inaccurate if it was parsed to integer.)